# I am trying to find the problem within this code

Tags: python

I was trying to run the code below when scraping data from a website:

```
for match in match_data:
    home_team.append(match.find('th', class_='fhome').get_text())
    score.append(match.find('th', class_='fscore').get_text())
    away_team.append(match.find('th', class_='faway').get_text())
```

then I got the error message below:

NameError: name 'home_team' is not defined

I tried to USE the code below:

```
for match in match_data:
    hometeam = home_team.append(match.find('th', class_='fhome').get_text())
    tscore = score.append(match.find('th', class_='fscore').get_text())
    awayteam = away_team.append(match.find('th', class_='faway').get_text())
```

But the error message is still the same as above

Comment: the error is self-explanatory. you need to have defined an array called home_team

Comment: well, you don't define a `home_team` anywhere in your code before you try to use it

Comment: You must declare hometeam as a variable first.  Likely putting hometeam = [] above for statement will fix error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise *all three variables* as empty lists *(`[]` or `list()`)* at the start of your code *(before your loop)*.

Otherwise, you have nothing to append your values to.  *(`append()` is just a method that exists on a `list` object.  Without storing a list in the variable first, there is nothing to call `append()` from.)*

```
home_team = []
score = []
away_team = []

for match in match_data:
    home_team.append(match.find('th', class_='fhome').get_text())
    score.append(match.find('th', class_='fscore').get_text())
    away_team.append(match.find('th', class_='faway').get_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to write `home_team = []` before the block of code. You have to define `home_team` as an empty list before appending to it.

Comment: Also; no need for `hometeam =`, as `append` will mutate the list.  `tscore = score.append()` looks like a typo, as does `awayteam = away_team.append()`, both of which also need initialising.